# Generate an infinite Stream<Integer> containing the integers (0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, ...)

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, java-stream

I am currently preparing for an exam and am working on the following task:

> Generate an infinite Stream containing the integers `(0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, ...)`.

Following stream generate a normal infinite stream:

```
Stream<Integer> infiniteStream = Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1);
```

Is there a method or lambda expression that produces both positive and negative numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Stream<Integer> infiniteStream = Stream.iterate(1, i -> i > 0 ? -i : (-i + 1));
```

Or, if you wish to start with `0`:

```
Stream<Integer> infiniteStream = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i > 0 ? -i : (-i + 1));
```

Of course, this can also be done with `IntStream`:

```
IntStream infiniteStream = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i > 0 ? -i : (-i + 1));
```

Comment: I already thought it would work with an intStream. But the task was explicitly related to a normal stream <Integer>. Thanks again

Comment: Note that this stream is infinite, but will produce meaningless numbers after reaching `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Once you accept the actual finite nature of the sequence, you may use `LongStream.rangeClosed(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE*2L+1).mapToInt(l -> -(int)((l>>1)^((l<<63)-(l&1))))` which has the great advantage that you can easily select an arbitrary sub-sequence efficiently rather than having to rely on expensive `skip()` and `limit()` operations…

Comment: @Holger this _seems_ like the same thing I tried to do with odd/even index (without the overhead of branching), but in a far more brilliant way, that I still can't understand...

Comment: @Eugene well, yes, that’s basically the same thing. You surely recognized the `>> 1` part, likewise, it is using the lowest one bit (even/odd indicator) to perform the change. Mind that `x ^ 0` evaluates to `x` whereas `x ^ 0xFFFF_FFFF` is the same as `~x` or `- x - 1`; only the lower 32 bits being relevant when casting to `int`. Using `.peek(l -> System.out.println(l+" -> "+(l>>1)+" ^ 0x"+Long.toHexString((l<<63)-(l&1))))` before the `mapToInt` step might illustrate it further.

Answer (score 3):

I want to provide an alternative to Erans answer.

Since you already know how the basic infinite stream works, you can use further stream operations like `flatMap` to build upon it:

```
    final Stream<Integer> eransAnswer = Stream.iterate(1, i -> i > 0 ? -i : (-i + 1));

    final Stream<Integer> alternative = Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1)
            .flatMap(i -> Stream.of(i, -i));

    System.out.println(eransAnswer.limit(6).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    System.out.println(alternative.limit(6).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Note that this only works if `flatMap` is lazily evaluated. I put the `limit` there so that I can collect it in some result (`toList`), but it also works with the `limit` after the `flatMap`.

Sometimes, instead of putting the "complexity" into your generating formula, it may or may not make sense to split it up and use intermediate stream operations. If your thought process is that you alternate numbers, use Erans answer. If you rather think that for the infinite stream of natural numbers, you want to duplicate each number with its inverse, than the intention is conveyed more clearly with the alternative.

EDIT: To handle the Zero, you can do `Stream.concat(Stream.of(0), alternative)`

Comment: I'd generate the `Stream` first and limit later, ie `Stream<Integer> alternative = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1).flatMap(i -> Stream.of(i, -i)); alternative.limit(6).forEach(i -> System.out.printf("%s ", i))`. It's more in the spirit of streams this way (especially for the alternative, where the actual logic isn't finished when the `limit()` is done).

Comment: Sure, that's possible. I just wanted to post code that does not crash and provide a way to check the output is the same (thus the sysout of the collected sample). I'll update the code, though.

Comment: Very nice alternative way to Erans.The .flatMap way is a good idea. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you look a bit closely to the scheme below, it's probably a lot easier than you might think:

```
0  1   2    3    4    5

|  |   |    |    |    |

0  1  (-1)  2   (-2)  3
```

Now, you can look at it this way: if the number is *even*, the result is that index divided by two (and minus that); if the number is *odd*, the result is that index divided by two plus 1.

You can tell if the number is odd or even, by simply looking at the last bit: if it is `1` => odd; if it is `0` => even. And you can divide a number by two by shifting it to the right once, as such:

```
IntStream.range(0, 10)
         .map(x -> (x & 1) == 0 ? -(x >> 1) : (x >> 1) + 1)
         .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the negative to lead off the pair of integers and show -1,1,-2,2,-3,3,.. you and do this.

```java
IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1).flatMap(a -> IntStream.of(-a, a));
IntStream.iterate(-1,i -> i < 0 ? -i: -i - 1);
```